# GETCHALLENGE issue(6D00) in EMV for MasterCard

Tags: emv

In the case of GETCHALLENGE Request (0084000000) in EMV, we are getting the positive response for VISA\DEBIT card, but for MASTERCARD we are getting the response as 6D00 (Instruction code not supported or invalid).

Here are the sequence of commands that are being executed prior to callling the Get Challenge in the case of MasterCard. The CDOL as you can see has the tag for ICC Dynamic number and when the call for getting the dynamic number by executing the get Challenge command, I get Instruction code not supported error message.

Answer To Reset

Response: 3b6d00000031c071d66419160100849000 Select Payment System Directory

Request : 00A404000E315041592E5359532E444446303100

Response : 6f1a840e315041592e5359532e4444463031a5088801015f2d02656e9000

Read Data

Request : 00B2010c00

Response : 701a61184f07a0000000041010500a4d6173746572436172648701019000

Select application

Request : 00A4040007a000000004101000

Response : 6f278407a0000000041010a51c500a4d6173746572436172648701015f2d02656ebf0c059f4d020b0a9000

Get Processing Options

Request : 80A8000002830000

Response : 770a820238009404100105019000

Internal Authenticate

Request : 0088000004E153F3E800

Response : 77539f4b508464f182032bd432f415ec7ddaa3e601526a2b860fcc9785475f8f45f095186e3658bc0a55bceb2d4c22fbded8af82bd81338e38961c5d000dd5a8f99d3ec0c774648534a2b362b55d4b9ee13f2043739000

Read data 
Request : 00B2011400

Response : 7081835f25031402015f24031703315a08XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5f3401019f0702ff008e10000000000000000042015e0342031f039f0d05b8500408009f0e0500008800009f0f05b8700498008c219f02069f03069f1a0295055f2a029a039c019f37049f35019f45029f4c089f34038d0c910a8a0295059f37049f4c085f280208409f4a01829000

Read data

Request : 00B2021400

Response : 70689f080200025711XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXd1703201021010792f5f2018XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX5f300202019f1f1a30303030303030323130313030303030303739323030303030309f420208409f4401029f49039f37049f4701039000

Read data

Request : 00B2031400

Response : 7081b79f4681b0c507d5fc6f008bf22f04484d0522f9a652df181559a938096558461a6a44a3acc8e1e64fb901a3bd5fa656ea1ec2eb2021d8ddab983aa5362ae0972bb717dc8f852da5a3ad03884c2ef06c4f2a7c56ff9891dd800707665569fb32bb05425c6d5a7461f2a604eb681d659bf052cad311af2b29e8a571a8e93a015814090eb13589e40756b5706e4e5bb75a1734f871aa6e6894f959f020854dfa9bca011340b470e5c45309f91486e7aa882a9109df708f01059000

Read data

Request : 00B2041400

Response : 7081b39081b057591da6a8901a96bb23f5ebbf6d86ae95b07395146a9a940833b1ba052e65676c9c4f7d0d86ec55f58a75647736b31895a7d1f439f777abc8866abd9054ebebed31f882fa05d6188da55f9a9ebf346e3a93e9cd0663fddaaa56f55d56ba37f5405804e873edd79fefd9957114e1c6826240b5ff049a0ea221310b1f25d6586863550673f979956de1df27f0bd91bfac6d4aa2b239d290b90a10b6b9f54ac006e3b917e3bb3e87e430ecb1927579fa979000

Read data

Request : 00B2051400

Response : 702a9f3201039224be09660a5a008739dcaa90106e2d4e0b99d3996fb7284012c1255c17e2709a52cdb9d7cb9000

Get Data - Application Transaction Counter

Request : 80CA9F3600

Response : 6a88

get Data - Last Online ATC Register

Request : 80CA9F1300

Response : 6a88

get data - Pin Try Counter

Request : 80CA9F1700

Response : 9f1701039000

get Data - Log format

Request : 80CA9F4F00

Response : 9f4f119f27019f02065f2a029a039f36029f52069000

GetChallenge

Request : 0084000000

Response : 6d00

Please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ICC Dynamic number for CDOL, After GPO, Internal authenticate need to be issued to the card. This will give you Signed Dynamic Application Data( which is a certificate signed under ICC Private Key ).

Below are the contents of the certificate you provided which I opened using your ICC Public Key. You can see ICC dynamic data of which 08 is the length and **C7C298C8C60E2984** is your dynamic number. Cheers, enjoy !!

As to how this is done, you need to read EMV 4.3 Book 2
Security and Key Management Section 6, Offline Dynamic Data Authentication. Happy learning. *Let me know once you complete, and accept this answer*

```
 DDA: Signed Dynamic Application Data Verification
 ****************************************
 ICC PK Modulus:
BC41FF9CEF143DBC67F3FBF9F17565F5C948B0106CFF664BCB54EE935AC5E2119B1879AB1DEF5F456FFB7C21FB30329FADE04E62E749719C7C2920B91E3C459712D296F2A0CB3566AA46C55DBBEA6BEB
 Signed Dynamic Application Data:
8464F182032BD432F415EC7DDAA3E601526A2B860FCC9785475F8F45F095186E3658BC0A55BCEB2D4C22FBDED8AF82BD81338E38961C5D000DD5A8F99D3EC0C774648534A2B362B55D4B9EE13F204373
 ----------------------------------------
 Recovered Data:                6A05010908C7C298C8C60E2984BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBF97A677485DC0A64971C54099583FBD0F39870D0BC
 Data Header:                   6A
 Signed Data Format:                05
 Hash Algorithm Indicator:          01
 Dynamic Data length:               09
 ICC Dynamic Data:              08C7C298C8C60E2984
 Pad Pattern:                   BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
 Hash Result:                   F97A677485DC0A64971C54099583FBD0F39870D0
 Data Trailer:                  BC
 ----------------------------------------
 Recovered Data validation:
 ----------------------------------------
 Step 1: Issuer PK Modulus and Signed Static Application Data having the same length: Passed
 Step 2: Recovered Data Trailer check:      Passed
 Step 3: Recovered Data Header check (0x6A):    Passed
 Step 4: Certificate Format check (0x03):   Passed
 Step 5: Hash Input Data:           05010908C7C298C8C60E2984BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBE153F3E8
 Step 6: Hashing Result:            F97A677485DC0A64971C54099583FBD0F39870D0
 Step 7: Hash Result Comparison:        Passed
 ----------------------------------------
 DDA Validation Succeed.
```

Comment: No, here for the CDOL (9F02069F03069F1A0295055F2A029A039C019F37049F35019F45029F4C089F3403) data, the tag for ICC dynamic number(9F4C) is present, in order to generate the Application cryptogram we need to include the ICC Dynamic number in the request. For getting the ICC Dynamic number we have to send the Getchallenge request, at that time we are getting the response as 6D00

Comment: Can you post your get processing options apdu and r-apdu too

Comment: Get Processing Options

APDU Request : 80A8000002830000,

APDU Response : 770a820238009404100105019000

Comment: Do an internal authenticate(00 88) with unpredictable number, as your DDOL says.You will get Signed Dynamic Application Data. Once you open, that SDAD should contain the ICC dynamic number i believe. Post your unpredictable number and sdad.

Comment: Request: 00880000041234567800, Response: 77539f4b501cc9fd64e1c5900f23f78ac766b074d38ea4c449d94da70958a8306ab3f58e44cbd205bc74401b8e5112f33c768718e37c0345c62728ecf2d895aa123b9b3c545fb7caf3dc20856b54df57620a4884279000, Unpredictable Number : 12345678, SDAD : 1CC9FD64E1C5900F23F78AC766B074D38EA4C449D94DA70958A8306AB3F58E44CBD205BC74401B8E5112F33C768718E37C0345C62728ECF2D895AA123B9B3C545FB7CAF3DC20856B54DF57620A488427

Comment: Can you check your READ DATA logs for the presence of 9F48( Integrated Circuit Card (ICC) Public Key Remainder ). This is missing in the what you pasted. ICC Public key certificate hash validation is failing probably because of this. Make sure you give the full information.

Comment: In my READ DATA the tag 9F48 is not present. Is there any issue from side for not getting the 9F48 tag in READ DATA?

Comment: 9F48 not available is not an issue. Is it possible that you can edit your question with the complete logs of a fresh transaction from pse till internal authenticate ? ICC certificate and corresponding data changes every time.

Comment: I said PSE till Internal authenticate. But you again gave for Get Challenge. I guess you are using MasterCard MTIP/NIV cards. In that case why are you masking the card and track data. I need the ODA elements from first READ as your AFL says. One thing i noticed is your ICC certificate is expired 03/17, it should cause an ODA fail in your case. However it does not have anything to do with what I am trying to do now. So redo and paste full logs till internal authenticate.

Comment: I have added internal authenticate after the get processing option request. When I tried internal authenticate after get challenge, I got the response as 6985. So I called internal authenticate after get processing option.

Comment: what about the masked data ?

Comment: Will provide you very soon once I got the permission from my manager. Sorry for the delay..

Comment: Not required. I have removed my original answer in context of offline enciphered PIN and updated it for your context so that it is less confusing and more useful for whoever who comes here later.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer once it work for you !!

Comment: I have a doubt regarding the Signing function values Sk and Pk in Cryptogram. Whether the Sk value corresponds to the tag 9F46 and Pk value corresponds to CA(Certification authority) Public Keys?

Comment: can you go to my answer in this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899196/emv-capk-selection/41908010#41908010 . I guess you are trying to understand what CA PK to use. btw you need to read more.

Comment: For another card the internal authenticate request and response is as follows. Here I am not getting the Signed Dynamic Application Data. Request  : 008800000468206B6600
Response : 8081808088911ddbd82daf214b2bc422d788c78b609e5892cc8bf5f60bf72c4836302536ee2947f7b470511bd03c20cf97b43929bbe1fdf38c946a5b82bae6909221fedd272df274888bb4d893bec591ec5c7701e9ab9a310616ff0c43d9782fed0c10e586d119ea9bceb8e0f805d831b3d21a00390c2c4f8336808ede31f753a388f79000

Comment: @AneeshVarghese can you use this link to parse the response. looks like there is some mistake in data you sent - https://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/